# How to change the button names on click

Tags: angularjs, templates, angular

I want to display the message 'request sent' while the button is clicked but  here  when  i  click  on  one button  all  the  button  names  are  changing.Can anyone suggest me  help.

```
import { Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import {Control,FormBuilder,ControlGroup,Validators} from '@angular/common';
import { IDetails } from './pro';
import {GetAllList } from './service'

@Component({
  templateUrl: './components/professional/professional.html',

providers :  [GetAllList]
})

export class Professional implements OnInit {
  id:number;
   profile_id:number;
  myText:string="Send Request";
  details:IDetails[];
  title:string = 'MY SOCIETY'; 
  constructor(private _service:GetAllList) {

   }
   ngOnInit(){
     this._service.getList()
             .subscribe(details => this.details = details); 
   }
    send(index):any{
   console.log(index);
     if(index == index){
     this.myText="Request sent";
     }
 }
}
```

My template,

```
    <h3 class= "head">MY SOCIETY</h3>  
    <!--<hr>-->
   <div *ngFor="let detail of details"  class = "col-sm-12"> 
    <div class="pic col-sm-1">
    <img  height="60" width="60" [src]='detail.image'>                 
   </div>
  <div class = "col-sm-6">
   <div class = "fname col-sm-12">
      {{detail.firstname}}
    </div>
  <div class ="phone col-sm-12">
    {{detail.phone}}
   </div>
     <div class ="phone col-sm-12">

    </div>
     </div>

    <button  (click)='send(detail.profile_id)' > {{ myText }}</button>

     <hr class= "col-xs-12"></div>
```

I want to display the message 'request sent' while the button is clicked but  here  when  i  click  on  one button  all  the  button  names  are  changing.Can anyone suggest me  help.

Comment: Where are the other buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy - just pass the button element as template variable:

```html
<button (click)='send(button, detail.profile_id)' #button>Send Request</button>
```

And in your component you can access the button to set the text and maybe disable it:

```ts
send(button, index): void {
    console.log(index);

    button.innerHTML = "Request sent";
    button.disabled = true;
}
```

---

> [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xq9lW26yKRG1omY2Ej9w?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: The names getting  refreshed  when i  refresh it  ,can u tell  me  hw  to  stable it even after  refreshing.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you refresh the page, the whole app get reinitialized and of course temporary values will be reset.

Comment: when i refresh it the  butoon properties also getting  refreshed,example the "request sent"   is  getting  back  to  "send  request".

Comment: Then you should save the state somewhere along with your `detail` variable.

Comment: Depends on where you need to save the state. I don't know anything about your project or workflow. Should it say `Request sent` for everyone or just for the person who pressed the button?

Comment: if i click "send request" for 1 person,it shows "request sent".Thats good but  when  i  refresh  the  page  for   the  same  person  the  buttons name is  going  back  to  "send  request".I want  to  fix  this.......